# Create VPS in GCP via Terraform module using count

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-modules

getting stuck with problem.
Need a terraform expert help. I want to create VPS in GCP with count using module. How to correct create and attach google_compute_address and google_compute_disk to each VPS with different names
Any help, please

Module code:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vps" {
  count               = var.server_count
  name                = var.server_count > 1 ? "${var.server_name}-${count.index}" : var.server_name
  description         = var.server_description
  machine_type        = var.server_type
  zone                = var.server_datacenter
  deletion_protection = var.server_delete_protection
  labels              = var.server_labels
  metadata            = var.server_metadata
  tags                = var.server_tags

  boot_disk {
    auto_delete = false
    initialize_params {
      size   = var.boot_volume_size
      type   = var.boot_volume_type
      image  = var.boot_volume_image
      labels = var.boot_volume_labels
    }
  }
  dynamic "attached_disk" {
    for_each = var.volumes
    content {
      source = attached_disk.value["volume_name"]
    }
  }

  dynamic "network_interface" {
    for_each = var.server_network
    content {
      subnetwork = network_interface.value["subnetwork_name"]
      network_ip = network_interface.value["subnetwork_ip"]
      dynamic "access_config" {
        for_each = network_interface.value.nat_ip ? [1] : []
        content {
          nat_ip = google_compute_address.static_ip.address
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "volume" {
  for_each = var.volumes
  name     = each.value["volume_name"]
  type     = each.value["volume_type"]
  size     = each.value["volume_size"]
  zone     = var.server_datacenter
  labels   = each.value["volume_labels"]
}

resource "google_compute_address" "static_ip" {
  count  = var.server_count
  name   = var.server_count > 1 ? "${var.server_name}-${count.index}" : var.server_name
  region = var.server_region
}
```

Using example:

```
module "vps-test" {
  source             = "../module"
  credentials_file   = "../../../../main/vault/prod/.tf/terraform-bb-prod-ground.json"
  server_count       = 2
  server_name        = "example-vps"
  server_description = "simple vps for module testing"
  server_type        = "e2-small"
  server_region      = "europe-west4"
  server_datacenter  = "europe-west4-c"
  server_labels = {
    project     = "terraform"
    environment = "test"
  }
  server_metadata = {
    groups = "parent_group.child_group"
  }
  boot_volume_image = "debian-cloud/debian-11"
  boot_volume_size  = 30
  boot_volume_labels = {
    environment = "production"
    project     = "v3"
    type        = "system"
  }
  server_tags              = ["postgres", "production", "disable-gce-firewall"]
  server_delete_protection = true
  server_network = {
    common_network = {
      subnetwork_name = "${data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.subnetwork_vpc_production_common_name}"
      subnetwork_ip   = ""
      nat_ip          = true
    } # },
    # custom_network = {
    #   subnetwork_name = (data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.subnetwork_vpc_production_k8s_name)
    #   subnetwork_ip   = ""
    #   nat_ip          = false
    # }
  }
  volumes = {
    volume_data1 = {
      volume_name = "v3-postgres-saga-import-test-storage"
      volume_size = "40"
      volume_type = "pd-ssd"
      volume_labels = {
        environment = "production"
        project     = "v3"
        type        = "storage"
      }
    },
    volume_data2 = {
      volume_name = "volume-vpstest2"
      volume_size = "20"
      volume_type = "pd-ssd"
      volume_labels = {
        environment = "production"
        project     = "v2"
        type        = "storage"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now error is: `Because google_compute_address.static_ip has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances` And i know, error with same disk name will come

Comment: You just need to use `count.index` object which is available when you use the `count` meta-argument, so you need `nat_ip = google_compute_address.static_ip[count.index].address`.

Comment: thank you, sir
what about disks same names ?

Comment: Hard to tell from the code, but try with this and if the error changes you can update the question.

Comment: Error: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: The disk resource 'projects/x-project/zones/europe-west4-c/disks/xxxxx-import-test-storage' is already being used by 'projects/x-project/zones/europe-west4-c/instances/example-vps-0', resourceInUseByAnotherResource

Comment: I don't know enough about GCP to make a comment. You should consider maybe opening another question for that particular issue.